# TinyMCE 5 - link image media icons not visible on Tablets and Smartphones

Tags: tinymce

I have added next icons to toolbar:

"toolbar" : "preview link image media"

But all these icons are visible on desktops only but not on tablets and phones.

How do I have them visible on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

On mobile browsers TinyMCE disables most plugins. We are working a fix so they're only disabled when using the mobile theme:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4848